# Application Freezes While Printing in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, printing, crystal-reports, ado.net

In my C# application, everything becomes frozen at the time of printing when the software runs in the network and multiple computers access the common database.

It doesn't always happen.

This is how I did the print job:

1. I include a dataset of my database in my project
2. Then I perform all print work from that dataset. I don't create ODBC connection for printing

Here is the code for printing:

```
using (ReportDocument rptDc = new ReportDocument())
{
    using (DataSet HospDataSet = new HospitalDataSet())
    {
        DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
        Dt.Columns.Add("Sr", typeof(int));
        Dt.Columns.Add("Query", typeof(string));
        Dt.Rows.Add(1, "select * from DG_Receipt where Id = " + SetId + "");
        Dt.Rows.Add(2, "select * from DG_Receipt_Detail where IdFk = " + SetId + " order by Sr");
        Dt.Rows.Add(3, "select * from DG_RefundMain where BillVouNo = (Select VouNo from DG_Receipt where Id = " + SetId + ")");
        Dt.Rows.Add(4, "select * from DG_Identity");

        using (DataSet Ds = GetPrintDetails(Dt, Con))
        {
            HospDataSet.Tables["DG_Receipt"].Merge(Ds.Tables[0]);
            HospDataSet.Tables["DG_Receipt_Detail"].Merge(Ds.Tables[1]);
            HospDataSet.Tables["DG_RefundMain"].Merge(Ds.Tables[2]);
            HospDataSet.Tables["DG_Identity"].Merge(Ds.Tables[3]);

            ReportPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Reports_DG\\rptDG_Receipt.rpt";
            rptDc.Load(ReportPath);

            rptDc.SetDataSource(HospDataSet);
            rpvHospitalReportViewer.ReportSource = rptDc;
            rptDc.PrintOptions.PrinterName = SetPrinterName;
            rptDc.PrintToPrinter(SetPrintCopies, false, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Please guys help me. What I am doing wrong here. It's a very serious issue for me.

**Edit**: I think it happens when the print job execute from multiple computers at the same time.

Comment: It's very unfortunate that no one is taking an interest :(

Comment: Hi, as I'm looking at it now it's been less than 30 minutes since you posted this. With 8 views in that time it's not that no one is taking interest but consider that on a Sunday activity might significantly less than on most other days. I took interest but it's not a scenario I've encountered and without a printer to reproduce the conditions I can't help immediately. You might have to wait a little longer for an answer

Comment: That said, how long does it take to recover from the freezing, if it does? In other words, does it stay frozen while the print job is executing the resume normal operations?

Comment: @Fabulous Thank you for your kind interest. It stays frozen until I press Ctrl+Alt+Del

Comment: @Fabulous Is it because I don't create ODBC on the client machine for printing? I simply install the setup and start the work.

Comment: I can't say for sure. If you put a breakpoint where you create the Dt `DataTable` and step through the code where does it get stuck?

Comment: But it's the issue on the client machine, how can I use the breakpoint. And it doesn't always happen. It happens especially when the print command executes from multiple computers at the same time.

Comment: just a guess, sometimes discovering printers takes a long time especially network printers. try manually printing something in Windows with the same printer and settings and see if it freezes there or not. Also you might want to add logging to this method, it can be frozen anywhere (accessing rpt file, accessing the folder, reading the datasource, discovering printers or sending the print to queue)

Comment: @Bizhan Should I fix the printer name in my code ?

Comment: If anything you should put the printer name in the configuration and not the code in case the users change the printer.